# How to plot a nonlinear system of 3 equations with 3 symbolic variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I don't have a lot of experience with Matlab. I know that you can plot equations with 2 variables like this:

```
ezplot(f1)
hold on
ezplot(f2)
hold off;
```

How would you plot three equations with **three** symbolic variables?

An example system would be:

```
x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0
2*x^2+y^2-4*z=0
3*x^2-4y+z^2=0
```

It would be ideal if there was a way to plot any system of 3 equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [`ezsurf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezsurf.html) comes close to what you want. You would first have to solve each equation for `z`, then make a function for that equation and plot it with `ezsurf`. Here's how to do it with your first equation from above:

```
func1 = @(x, y) sqrt(1-x.^2-y.^2);
ezsurf(func1);
```

This should display the upper half of a sphere.

To display all three equations together, you can do the following:

```
func1 = @(x, y) sqrt(1-x.^2-y.^2);
func2 = @(x, y) 0.5.*x.^2+0.25.*y.^2;
func3 = @(x, y) sqrt(4.*y-3.*x.^2);
ezsurf(func1, [-1 1 -1 1]);
hold on;
ezsurf(func2, [-1 1 -1 1]);
ezsurf(func3, [-1 1 -1 1]);
axis([-1 1 -1 1 0 1]);
```

and the resulting plot will look like this:

[image]

By rotating the plot, you will notice that there appear to be two points where all three surfaces intersect, giving you two solutions for the system of equations.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful and I'm accepting your answer.

I know I can use solve(f1,z) for example to solve it for z. But how would I pass the returned function to ezsurf?

I tried
f = x^2+y^2+z^2-1;
f = solve(f, z);
func1 = @(x,y) f;
ezsurf(func1);

That obviously doesn't work but I'm asking is there a way to do it?

Comment: The correct syntax for the way you want to do it would be the following:   f = 'x^2+y^2+z^2-1';   f2 = solve(f,'z');   ezsurf(f2(1));   hold on;   ezsurf(f2(2));   axis equal;   This will plot both the top and the bottom of the sphere, unfortunately with a jagged discontinuity between the surfaces at the "equator". To get around the discontinuity, you would have to use SURF instead of EZSURF and define for yourself the x and y points at which the surface will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

"hold on" just says to not erase existing lines & markers on the current axis. you should just be able to do

```
ezplot(f1);
hold on;
ezplot(f2);
ezplot(f3);
hold off;
```

I've never used ezplot so can't help you with that one.

Comment: Unfortunately ezplot can work only with functions of no more than two symbolic variables. What I am looking for is a way to plot a function of 3 variables. It doesn't need to be ezplot.

Comment: Oops, I caught the "3 equations" but missed the "3 variables" part.