# How to use ezplot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to use `ezplot` in MATLAB, and because the function I want to plot consists of a large number of terms I may split it into smaller functions. Let me give an example of a small number of terms and it can be generalized to a large number of terms. To plot the function:

```
y2+xy+xy3+x+1=0
```

I let `y1=x+1` and I write the following in MATLAB:

```
x=[0:1:5]
y1=x+1
ezplot('y.^2+x*y+x*y.^3+y1')
```

But there is an error. Please tell me how can I correct the error. Is it possible to use this feature (splitting the equation or function into a number of terms)?

Answer (score 10):

Your error is caused by trying to replace `x+1` with `y1`. [`ezplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html) requires that symbolic expressions are functions of only 2 symbolic variables. However, there are **3** symbolic variables (`x`, `y`, and `y1`) in your call to `ezplot`:

```
ezplot('y^2+x*y+x*y^3+y1');
```

If you use your original equation, everything should work fine:

```
ezplot('y^2+x*y+x*y^3+x+1');
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** In case you were curious...

If you want to plot an equation with 3 variables, you will first need to solve the equation for one of them and then use the function [`ezsurf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezsurf.html) (this is illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926307/52738) I gave to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/925555/52738)). Technically, `y1` is a *dependent* variable the way you have defined it (since it depends on the variable `x`). However, for the sake of the following example, let's assume it's an *independent* variable. The equation:

```
y^2 + x*y + x*y^3 + y1 = 0
```

would be solved for `y1` to get the following:

```
y1 = -y^2 - x*y - x*y^3
```

and `y1` would be plotted in the following way:

```
ezsurf('-y^2-x*y-x*y^3');
```

[image]