# Plot with ezplot whit coefficients

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation

I'm doing my homework and i am calculating linear interpolations for some points.
Well i do this with a linear system and solving this.s
But when i have the result, a vector with te cofficients, i don't know how can i plot it.
Somebody know some way?
This is an exemple i want plot R

`A = [1 1 1; 4 2 1; 16 4 1];
B = [0; 2; 12];
R = linsolve(A,B);
T = 9*R(1) + 3 * R(2) + R(3)`

The first thing i have thinked is write a function but has matlab a expecific function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ezplot](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html) function of `matlab`. I'm not sure about what you need, so I hope this will help. You have the coefficients so just get the function and pass it to the function `ezplot`. Something like this :

**UPDATE :**

```
func = "";
for k=1:length(R)
 func = func + x^k;
end
```

And then :

```
 ezplot(R);
```

Comment: But this do: R(1) x^2 + R(2)*x + R(3)??

Comment: You want to plot the vector R, don't you ?

Comment: No sorry i have said it wrong. I want plot the polinomy which have this coefficients.

Comment: Take a look at this : http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179175/how-to-use-ezplot-in-matlab?rq=1

Comment: Yes but here they have the equation, i only have the coefficients. My dubt was if i need build the equation or matlab had some funciton for coefficients. Thanks