# How to plot (surf) vectorized (Matrix shaped) equation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, surface

I want to `surf` this function:

```
z=w.'*p %(close form)
```

Which:

```
w=[w0; w1]
p=[cte0; cte1]
```

There, w is variable and cte0 and cte1 can be any number.
To using `surf` we need to generate w0 and w1 by `meshgrid`:

```
[w0,w1]=meshgrid(-50:1:50)
```

Now we can only reach answer by manipulating equation ( `z=w.'*p`) to this form:

```
z=w0*cte0+w1*cte1 %(open form)
surf(z)
```

I don't want to manipulate my equation, since in other case, bigger equation is not so easy to manipulate them.
Is there any way to simply reach surface in this close form other than symbolic toolbox?

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: You're not using a symbolic toolbox here.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I don't want to visualize it in open form, I want to visualize it in close form? Is any other solution more than symbolic toolbox exist?

Comment: You need to be more clear. What do you mean open/close form? whatever way you create the fucntion, the surface is still the same, visually it must not change

Comment: Are you looking for something like `ezsurf` (or the newer [`fsurf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fsurf.html))? Related questions: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/925555/52738), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1179175/52738)

Comment: @AnderBiguri : I manipulated equation in vector form(close form), by this we achieve ability to using `meshgrid()` (in open form), I want to obtain surface by using meshgrid, without manipulating main equation--close form means matrix form--. @gnovice : No.

Comment: What is `z` supposed to be for a given `w`? Should it be a scalar or a 2-by-2 matrix, because your two different "forms" (closed versus open) give different results given how you have defined `w` and `p`.

Comment: @gnovice : sorry now edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's say you start with your "close form" equation as an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
z = @(w) w.'*p;
```

Which assumes `p` has already been defined and requires an input that is 2-by-1. How will any high-level plotting routines in MATLAB (like [`fsurf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fsurf.html), for example) know that the input should be 2-by-1 (i.e. a set of independent variables `[x; y]`)? They won't, unless you wrap this function in another function like so:

```
fxy = @(x, y) z([x; y]);
```

So, this function expects two variables as input, and will concatenate them and pass them in the right form to the function `z`. But how will the function `fxy` handle vector or matrix inputs for `x` or `y`? Not well, so we'll have to add another layer of wrapping to handle that (courtesy of [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)):

```
fxyMat = @(x, y) arrayfun(fxy, x, y);
```

Now you have a function that takes vector or matrix inputs for two variables and ultimately evaluates your original, unaltered equation. You can now use `fsurf` to plot it without explicitly evaluating it at a number of points yourself (basically, you are letting `fsurf` do it for you):

```
p = [1; 2];
z = @(w) w.'*p;
fxy = @(x, y) z([x; y]);
fxyMat = @(x, y) arrayfun(fxy, x, y);
fsurf(fxyMat, [-50 50]);
```

And here's the plot (just a simple tilted plane for this example):

[image]

Comment: Explained nicely, But, after running your code, Why this is not valid: `surf(fxyMat(w0,w1))`? `w0` and `w1` are which defined in main question by `meshgrid`. Exactly `fxyMat(w0,w1)` isn't valid.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd: How is it not valid? It evaluates just fine for me. Are you getting an error? This gives me the same plot as `fsurf`, just a higher resolution: `surf(w0, w1, fxyMat(w0, w1));`

Comment: It worked, this is not simple :( but working well, ty.

Answer (score 0):

```
[w0,w1] = meshgrid(-50:1:50) ;

cte0 = rand ;
cte1 = rand ;
p = [repmat(cte0,size(w0)) ; repmat(cte1,size(w1))] ;
w = [w0 ; w1] ;
Z = w.*p ;
```

Comment: It's smart, but it have something missed. answer is not completely correct even by replacing `Z = w.*p;` by `Z = w.'*p;`. This is check code: `[w0,w1] = meshgrid(-50:1:50) ;
cte0 = 2 ;
cte1 = 2 ;
p = [repmat(cte0,size(w0)) ; repmat(cte1,size(w1))] ;
w = [w0 ; w1] ;
Z = w.'*p ;
surf(w0,w1,Z)
figure

syms w0;
syms w1;
w=[w0;w1];
Z = w.'*[2; 2] ;
fmesh(Z,[-50 50]);`